# Sliding home page conent

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I'm wanting to create a sliding carousel similar to the one used here: http://www.oki-ni.com/

Any ideas on how I Would go about doing it?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to go about doing this, but Javascript/jQuery is typically how it is done.

There are tons of jQuery slider downloads out there, just google for it.  Here is an example.

http://www.basic-slider.com/

If you'd like to follow a tutorial and create your own instead of downloading one:

http://designmodo.com/image-slider-jquery-css3/